# Guardar una imagen en MySQL desde C#, cambio de cantidad de bytes

Tags: mysql, c#, picturebox, byte

tengo un problema al momento de querer guardar una imagen en MySQL desde C#, al momento de obtener la imagen se tiene una cadena de bytes, pero cuando la obtengo desde la base de datos, esta cadena es menor a como la envio. Adjunto ejemplos de lo anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de obtenerla para colocarla en un PictureBox, regresa de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe por que sucede esto?

Para realizar la consulta a la base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

```
objDataBase.DtParametros.Rows.Add(@"_PACIENTE_FOTO", "23", objPaciente.Foto);
```

Se obtienen de esta manera por que se esta realizando el sistema en capas, el segundo parametro indica el tipo de dato en la base de datos, que en este caso 23 lo tengo en un switch como:

```
case "23":
TipoDatoMySQL = MySqlDbType.LongBlob;
```

Comment: El problema puede estar al guardar la fotografía, adjunta más código tanto del guardado, como la asignación del valor al picturebox, a veces si no se le da el tamaño exacto del vector de bytes, al enviar la data, el blob se corrompe, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo tenia el mismo problema, lo pude solucionar cambiando el modo en el que guardaba el array de bytes en la base de datos, antes hacia esto:

```
try
        {
            string query = $"INSERT INTO documentos (nombre_archivo, datos_archivo) VALUES ('{fileName}', '{fileData}')";
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(query);
            comando.Connection = conexionBD;
            conexionBD.Open();
            comando.ExecuteReader();
            conexionBD.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Pero esto esta mal y es una mala practica ya que pueden hacernos un sqlInyection, el metodo correcto para guardar los datos es:

```
public async Task UploadFile(byte[] fileData, string fileName)
    {
        DataConexion.getConnectionString();
        var conexionBD = await DataConexion.conectar();


        try
        {
            string query = $"";
            var command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO documentos (nombre_archivo, datos_archivo) VALUES (@fileName, @fileData)", conexionBD);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileData", fileData);
            
            conexionBD.Open();
            var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            conexionBD.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Ya con esto te aseguras que estas guardando todos los bytes en la base de datos, espero que pueda ayudar a alguien.